# Sort images according to their type and put them in a the corresponding folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, sorting

I would like to sort images according to their type (good, medium, bad) and put them in the corresponding folder.

My data is an object with image name + label

```
export interface data = { image: string, label: 'good' | 'medium' | 'bad' }
export const DATA: data = {
 { image: 'name-of-image-1, label: 'good' }
 { image: 'name-of-image-2, label: 'bad' },
 { image: 'name-of-image-3, label: 'good' },
 ...,
 { image: 'name-of-image-n, label: 'medium' }
}
```

Images are on a server, the path is for instance: `smb://test/images/`

So I find my first image at `smb://test/images/name-of-image-1`

I would like to map my DATA array and copy images in the corresponding folder depending of the label. For example, put image with label `bad` in the folder `./bad`.

Have you an idea to do that with Node?

Comment: One possible starting point: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: I use fs.copyFile but i have an error : [Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, copyfile './package.json' -> './data'] {
  errno: -21,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  path: './package.json',
  dest: './data'
}

Comment: Please add this code to your question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your provided code example has some issues which are solved here:

```
export interface Data {
    image: string,
    label: 'good' | 'medium' | 'bad'
}

export const data: Data[] = [
    { image: 'name-of-image-1', label: 'good' },
    { image: 'name-of-image-2', label: 'bad' },
    { image: 'name-of-image-3', label: 'good' },
    { image: 'name-of-image-n', label: 'medium' }
];
```

To solve your problem you coude use `.reduce` to group the image `label` accordingly:

```
const sorted = data.reduce((prev, current) => ({
    ...prev,
    [current.label]: [
        ...prev[current.label],
        current.image
    ]
}), { good: [], medium: [], bad: [] });
```

The response of `sorted` is then the following

```
{
    "good": [
        "name-of-image-1",
        "name-of-image-3"
    ],
    "medium": [
        "name-of-image-n"
    ],
    "bad": [
        "name-of-image-2"
    ]
}
```

Comment: yes this part I succeeded, but i dont know how to put image in folder :/